# How can I stop my Javascript code from messing up my predefined CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a mini-email platform. It is a mockup and not exactly a full application. I have some dummy emails in the HTML file which I have styled. I added an input bar and then used javascript to display emails that correspond with the value in the search bar. My code works but it messes up the CSS styles I have set and the displayed values are scattered around.

How can I make sure that my Javascript code adheres to my predefined CSS styles?

*HTML*

```
 <section id="email">
    <div class = "date-container">
      <div class = "calendar-container">
        <img src="./assets/icon_calender.svg" alt="">
        <div>
          <span>2019/12/31 - 2020/1/3</span>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./assets/icon_search.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "text-container email">
      <h1>Results: <span>10</span>mail(s)</h1>
      <input class="search-email" type="text" placeholder="search">
    </div>
    <div class = "email-table">
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>From <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
           <th>To</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th class="date">Date <span><img src="./assets/icon_arrow01.svg" alt=""></span></th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="email-body">
           
           <td>aaa@example.com</td>
           <td class="second-data first-second-data">zzz.zzz@example.com</td>
           <td class="third-data first-third-data">[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement</td>
           <td>0:20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="email-body">
          <td>bbb.bbbb@exam... </td>
          <td class="second-data second-second-data">yyy@example.com</td>
          <td class="third-data second-third-data">[web:333] "Web Contact"</td>
          <td>0:10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>ccc@example.com </td>
          <td class="second-data third-second-data">
            <div class="text-attachment">
              <span>xxx@example.com, ...</span>
              <span>+1</span>
            </div>
             </td>
          <td class="third-data third-third-data">Happy New Year! Greetings for the New Year.</td>
          <td>
            <div class="attachment first-clip">
              <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span> 
              <span>0:00</span>
              </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>ddd.dddd@exam...</td>
          <td class="second-data fourth-second-data">
            <div class="text-attachment second-text">
              <span>vvv.vvv@example.com, ... </span>
              <span>+1</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="third-data fourth-third-data">[HR-887(Revised: Office Expansion Project Team)] Notice of off... </td>
          <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">

          <td>eee@example.com</td>
          <td class="second-data fifth-second-data">
            <div class="text-attachment last-attachment">
              <span>sss@example.com, .... </span>
              <span>+2</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="third-data fifth-third-data">[Github] Logout page</td>
          <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>fff.ffff@example.c... </td>
          <td>qqq.qqq@example.com</td>
          <td>［dev］ Postfix 3.1.12 / 3.2.9 / 3.3.4 / 3.4.5</td>
          <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>ggg@example.com </td>
          <td>ppp@example.com</td>
          <td>Re: [Github] Brush-up on loading animation </td>
          <td>Jan 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>hhh.hhh@examp...</td>
          <td>ooo.ooo@example.com</td>
          <td>Workplace Summary for sample, Inc.: Jun 2 - Jun 9</td>
          <td>
            <div class="attachment">
          <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span> 
          <span>Jan 01</span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>iii@example.com</td>
          <td>nnn@example.com</td>
          <td>I love you</td>
          <td>
            <div class="attachment last-clip">
              <span><img src="./assets/icon_clip.svg" alt=""></span> 
              <span>2019/12/31</span>
              </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="email-body">
          <td>Pablo-Diego-...</td>
          <td>Pablo-Diego-José-Francisc...
          </td>
          <td>[info:888] ABC EQUIPMENT COMPANY</td>
          <td>2019/12/31</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.email{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.email input[type= "text"]{
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.text-container h1{
  color: #5E5D5D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.text-container h1>span{
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
.text-container hr{
  border-top: 1px solid #E0DEDE;
}

.image-container img{
  margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
  display: block;
  
}
#email{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.email-table{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px 40px 5px 0px;
}
.email-table table{
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th:first-of-type>span img{
  display: none;
}
td, th {
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
td{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

td:last-of-type{
  font-weight: 700;
}
.attachment{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  
  
}

.first-clip span:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.last-clip{
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.attachment span:last-of-type{
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.attachment span:first-of-type img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.text-attachment{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.text-attachment span:first-of-type{
  transform: translateX(-18px);
}
.second-text{
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

.text-attachment span:last-of-type{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #5E5D5D;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.second-text span:last-of-type{
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}
td  img{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}

th{
  background-color: #EEEDED;
  border-top: 3px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dddddd;
}
th:not(:last-child){
  color: #5E5D5D;
}
.date>span img{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
tr:not(:first-of-type):hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #EEEDED;
}
tr td:last-of-type>span img{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateX(90px);
  display: none;
}
.first-clip span:last-of-type>span img{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateX(90px);
  display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const searchEmail = document.querySelector('.search-email');

searchEmail.addEventListener('keyup', filterEmail);

function filterEmail (e){
  const emailText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('.email-body').forEach((email) =>{
    const emailItem = email.innerHTML;
    if(emailItem.toLowerCase().indexOf(emailText) != -1){
      email.style.display ='block'
    }else{
      email.style.display ='none'
    }
  })
  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your `email.style.display ='block'` to `email.style.display =''`.

Also you might want to consider settings your table width and td widths to percentages so that your table columns stays the same all the time, not depending on content.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it totally.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code I see that there is a problem with your Javascript displaying all the results in one table column. That is caused by the if statement displaying everything as a block. So to fix your problem you just need to change your logic:

*Javascript*

```
const searchEmail = document.querySelector('.search-email');

searchEmail.addEventListener('keyup', filterEmail);

function filterEmail (e){
  const emailText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('.email-body').forEach((email) =>{
    const emailItem = email.innerHTML;
    if(emailItem.toLowerCase().indexOf(emailText) == -1)
    {
      email.style.display ='none'
    }
    else 
    {
      email.style.display =''
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This does not set table back when search is empty....

Comment: You are right I fixed it . You just need to change the style back to empty '' if it is supposed to be showing.